# Valgrind: Invalid read / write of size 1 Ask

Tags: c, string

I try to write a code which can replace certain words or characters in a string. Although output seems great, I got some error by using `valgrind`. Can anyone help?

```
01: #include <stdio.h>
02: #include <stdlib.h>
03: #include <string.h>
04: 
05: char *changewords (char *sentence, char *find, char *replace)
06: {
07:     size_t len_total =  0;
08: 
09:     char *dest = malloc (len_total + 1);
10:     char *destptr = dest;
11: 
12:     *dest = 0;
13: 
14:     while (*sentence)
15:     {
16:         if (!strncmp (sentence, find, strlen(find)))
17:         {
18:             len_total += strlen(replace);
19:             dest = realloc(dest, len_total + 1);
20:             *destptr = 0;
21:             strcat (destptr, replace);
22:             sentence += strlen(find);
23:             destptr += strlen(replace);
24:         } else
25:         {
26:             len_total++;
27:             dest = realloc(dest, len_total + 1);
28:             *destptr = *sentence;
29:             destptr++;
30:             sentence++;
31:         }
32: 
33:     }
34:     *destptr = 0;
35:     return dest;
36: }
37: 
38: int main (void)
39: {
40:     char *result;
41: 
42:     result = changewords ("i like it", "i", "ooooooooo");
43:     printf ("%s\n", result);
44:     free (result);
45: }
```

### Valgrind report:

```
==20396== Invalid write of size 1
==20396==    at 0x40076F: changewords (changeword4.c:22)
==20396==    by 0x400815: main (changeword4.c:45)
==20396==  Address 0x5204040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 free'd
==20396==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20396==    by 0x400766: changewords (changeword4.c:21)
==20396==    by 0x400815: main (changeword4.c:45)
==20396==  Block was alloc'd at
==20396==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20396==    by 0x400701: changewords (changeword4.c:11)
==20396==    by 0x400815: main (changeword4.c:45)
==20396== 
==20396== Invalid read of size 1
==20396==    at 0x4C30C04: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20396==    by 0x400784: changewords (changeword4.c:23)
==20396==    by 0x400815: main (changeword4.c:45)
==20396==  Address 0x5204040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 free'd
==20396==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20396==    by 0x400766: changewords (changeword4.c:21)
==20396==    by 0x400815: main (changeword4.c:45)
==20396==  Block was alloc'd at
==20396==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20396==    by 0x400701: changewords (changeword4.c:11)
==20396==    by 0x400815: main (changeword4.c:45)
==20396== 
==20396== Invalid write of size 1
==20396==    at 0x4C30C30: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20396==    by 0x400784: changewords (changeword4.c:23)
==20396==    by 0x400815: main (changeword4.c:45)
==20396==  Address 0x5204040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 free'd
==20396==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20396==    by 0x400766: changewords (changeword4.c:21)
==20396==    by 0x400815: main (changeword4.c:45)
==20396==  Block was alloc'd at
==20396==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20396==    by 0x400701: changewords (changeword4.c:11)
==20396==    by 0x400815: main (changeword4.c:45)
==20396== 
==20396== Invalid write of size 1
==20396==    at 0x4C30C3F: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20396==    by 0x400784: changewords (changeword4.c:23)
==20396==    by 0x400815: main (changeword4.c:45)
==20396==  Address 0x5204049 is 8 bytes after a block of size 1 free'd
==20396==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20396==    by 0x400766: changewords (changeword4.c:21)
==20396==    by 0x400815: main (changeword4.c:45)
==20396==  Block was alloc'd at
==20396==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20396==    by 0x400701: changewords (changeword4.c:11)
==20396==    by 0x400815: main (changeword4.c:45)
==20396== 
==20396== Invalid write of size 1
==20396==    at 0x4007D2: changewords (changeword4.c:30)
==20396==    by 0x400815: main (changeword4.c:45)
==20396==  Address 0x5204049 is 8 bytes after a block of size 1 free'd
==20396==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20396==    by 0x400766: changewords (changeword4.c:21)
==20396==    by 0x400815: main (changeword4.c:45)
==20396==  Block was alloc'd at
==20396==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20396==    by 0x400701: changewords (changeword4.c:11)
==20396==    by 0x400815: main (changeword4.c:45)
==20396== 
==20396== Invalid write of size 1
==20396==    at 0x4007F1: changewords (changeword4.c:36)
==20396==    by 0x400815: main (changeword4.c:45)
==20396==  Address 0x5204061 is 17 bytes after a block of size 16 in arena "client"
==20396== 

==20396== 
==20396== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20396==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20396==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 11 frees, 1,215 bytes allocated
==20396== 
==20396== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==20396== 
==20396== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20396== ERROR SUMMARY: 43 errors from 6 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

### Output:

```
ooooooooo loooooooooke ooooooooot
```

Comment: You should not realloc so often. There has to be a more efficient way.

Comment: Do you mean I had better realloc before return instead of inside while loop?

Comment: Allocate initially at least enough space to hold the original string and then use some prediction, realloc by adding a block of some N chars at once instead of 1 char, maybe doubling N every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *dest = malloc (len_total + 1);
char *destptr = dest;
```

Okay, so `destptr` points into the block that `dest` points to.

```
dest = realloc(dest, len_total + 1);
*destptr = *sentence;
```

You dereference `destptr` while it points into the block you just reallocated. That can't be right. Start by swapping the order of those last two statements.

Comment: but I should allocate memory for it before assigning it a character, shouldn't I?

Comment: @linpohsien You already did. The very first line of code allocated space.

Comment: but it only allocate one space for null terminated character

Comment: @linpohsien Right, so what's the issue? `*destptr = *sentence;` only copies one character.